# how to make value dynamic while copying data from one workbook to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have to copy the data of product category A01 to another workbook having a sheet named A01. but the product categories have A011,A012,A013 and so on data also. so, for that I want to make it dynamics.

I tried:

```
Sub left()
vcounter = Workbooks("macro tool.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row
For k = 1 To 9
For j = 2 To vcounter
    If Workbooks("macro tool.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(j, 3).Value = "A01" & k Then
        Workbooks("macro tool.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet1").Rows(j).Copy
        Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets("A01").Activate
        vcounter1 = Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets("A01").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row
        Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets("A01").Cells(vcounter1 + 1, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial
    End If
Next j
Next k
End Sub
```

the output of this program is:

```
A011
A011
A011
A011
A012
A012
A012
A012
A012
A012
A012
A012
A013
A013
A013
A013
A013
A013
A013
A013
A013
A014
A014
A014
A015
A015
A015
A015
A015
A015
A016
A016
A016
A016
A016
A016
A016
A016
A017
A017
A017
A017
A017
A017
A018
A018
A018
A018
A018
A018
A018
A019
A019
A019
A019
A019
```

and not giving the values for

```
A01
```

I wrote the following code:

```
Sub left()
vcounter = Workbooks("macro tool.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row

For j = 2 To vcounter
    If Workbooks("macro tool.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(j, 3).Value = left(Range("C" & j), 3) = "A01" Then
        Workbooks("macro tool.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet1").Rows(j).Copy
        Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets("A01").Activate
        vcounter1 = Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets("A01").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row
        Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets("A01").Cells(vcounter1 + 1, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial
    End If
Next j
End Sub
```

but this is not working as I used the left function with value.

I want both the values having product code A01 as well as other values, thats why I tried to use left function but the code isn't working. it is not giving any error but also not giving any output too.

Answer (score 0):

Sub left()
vcounter = Workbooks("macro tool.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row
For k = 1 To 9
Workbooks("macro tool.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet1").Rows(1).Copy Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets("A0" & k).Rows(1)
 For j = 2 To vcounter
If left(Workbooks("macro tool.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C" & j), 3) = "A0" & k Then
Workbooks("macro tool.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet1").Rows(j).Copy
        Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets("A0" & k).Activate
        vcounter1 = Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets("A0" & k).Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row
        Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets("A0" & k).Cells(vcounter1 + 1, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial
    End If
 Next j
 Next k
End Sub

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
If left(Workbooks("macro tool.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(j, 3).Value,3) = left(Range("C" & j), 3) = "A01" Then
```

Comment: this one didn't work. but I made some changes and then it works. thank you

Comment: @aakanshashankhala Please post what worked as an Answer. Stack Overflow is a Q&A repository - questions without answers are poor for site quality.